# Device.OS in Xaml in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

How to write (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android) in xaml,

In My class file i created like this in c#, but i don't know how to write this in xaml,

```
  if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android) 
  {
        var stack = new StackLayout()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        };
         var label = new Label()
        {
            Content = "This design is for Android"
        };
        stack.Children.Add(label);       

    };

    if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
    {
        var grid = new Grid()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };
        var label = new Label()
        {
            Content = "This design is for IOS"
        };
        grid.Children.Add(label);
    }
```

Please help me how to write this two different design in android and IOS in xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible in XAML, at least not like this. Two options come to mind:

Create two pages in XAML, one for Android and one for iOS and push the right page depending on the platform, basically with the if from your code.

Or, implement something like this in one page:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.IsVisible>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">                   
            <OnPlatform.iOS>false</OnPlatform.iOS>           
            <OnPlatform.Android>true</OnPlatform.Android>           
         </OnPlatform>
    </StackLayout.IsVisible>
</Stacklayout>
```

And for the grid the other way around. Note: the latter might negatively impact your layout cycle

PS. `Device.OS` is deprecated, you should use `Device.RuntimePlatform` now.